# How to excape special syntax characters in string variable in bash

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

**GIVEN:**

A string variable containing characters that are used by `bash` for expansion or as delimiters, e.g.

```
> path="/this/path/contains whitespace/and/asterisk */myfile.txt"
```

**GOAL:**

I want to expand the variable in a way that those `bash` syntax elements are backslashed (or disabled but not simply quoted), i.e. the output of `solution` would be

```
> solution $path
/this/path/contains\ whitespace/and/asterisk\ \*/myfile.txt
```

**QUESTION:**

Isn't there a command in `bash` that does that, rather than having to struggle with all special characters on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%q` specifier of `printf` (a bash builtin):

```
path="/this/path/contains whitespace/and/asterisk */myfile.txt"
printf '%q\n' "$path"
```

Comment: Recent (5.0+?) versions also support `escaped=${original@Q}`

Comment: You have to be careful with, e.g. `${original@Q}` which may simply single-quote the string.